# PHP email form doesnt work correctly

Tags: php

I have on the web email form, when I type all the informations it sends me an email, however when I type some czech characters (the site is czech) it doesnt work. Some of the characters shows as "ÄŤĹ™ĹľĂ˝ĂˇĂ­" for example. I downloaded free template from some website, which I edited with my friend who knows HTML, but not PHP. I tried to find out some advice, but it says nothing to me, because I dont know almost anything about PHP and when I tried to copy some part of the code and hoped that it will worked it havent... Can you please help me?

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'xxxx@pl.cz'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' 
replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a 
message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "Nova zprava z webu.\n\n"."Udaje:\n\nJmeno: $name\nEmail: 
$email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@plantaen.cz\n"; // We recommend using something 
like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: set a mail header for the charset you are using

Comment: It always surprises me when someone `returns true` without any form of exception handling.

Comment: @ggdx - indeed, even `return mail(....);` here would be better, and simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Add header to mail

Try this:

```
$body = '<html><head><title>Title</title></head>'."\r\n";
$body .= 'Test';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: YourName <"from@yoruname.com">';

mail("to@yourname.com","title",$body,$headers);
```

Edit :

```
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
     echo "No arguments Provided!";
     exit();
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";

    $email_body = '<html><head><title>plantaen</title></head>'."\r\n";
    $email_body .= "Nova zprava z webu.\n\n"."Udaje:\n\nJmeno: $name\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: plantaen <"noreply@plantaen.cz">';

    mail("noreply@plantaen.cz", $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

    echo "Done!";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you put it right into my code please? I am so bad and I dont want to destroy it completly.

Comment: but only if the OP is actually using utf-8

Comment: @tobiasekll check answer

Comment: into mail("noreply@plantaen.cz"  should I write email where I want to receive all the email from site right?

If yes it seems it doesnt work at all...